# Salesforce validations

Tags: salesforce

I'm new in Salesforce and I have to create an app for gym owner.

I made 3 objects, Member, Membership and Booking. My member object has data about gym members like address, date of birth etc.
Membership object has fields like MEMBER(lookup relationship with Member object), START DATA, END DATE and ACTIVE (checkbox to see if membership is stil active).

If membership of that member is still active, I have to prevent customer to create another membership for that member until current expires. How can I do that?

Comment: I think you should scrap the Member object and use the salesforce Contact object. You can then create an apex trigger to see if the member is active. if it is active you can use the AddError method that each sObject has. You might also receive more help using https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could pull something like that with validation rule using VLOOKUP function (but then you need to always put something fairly unique & predictable in the `Name` field on your membership object). I'm thinking something along the lines of "if there exists membership 'Member #1234 active' then VLOOKUP should prevent creating another one like that".

A nasty user could then delete the membership, create new one and restore it from recycle bin :P

So I have better idea for you (still without using any code). Convert membership->member lookup to master-detail relation. This would let you create rollup summary fields, read up about them. Create a rollup field that would be COUNT() of active memberships for the guy. Make validation rule that throws tantrum when you insert new membership and the count is already > 0.

Comment: Thanks, I already did that by myself and it works (Master-detail and Rollup) :)

I have next tasks to work on:
1.) We should be able to schedule new Personal Training / Massage. This should be done using some sort of calendar that would show only available appointments for selected location and date/week.
2.) Customer should be getting following notifications
- When new booking is made
- One month before his gym membership expires

Do you know how to resolve any of these problems?

Comment: These are new questions and not necessarily programming-related. Admins & devs at salesforce.stackexchange.com might give you better help, community here is really more about coding stuff up. #2 can be solved with (old school) workflow rules and email alerts or (new & hip) Process Builder. You'd need time-based action to solve the "1 month before date X". Try googling around and if you're stuck - raise new question.